# "Pkg: Error reading from file" in Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am not able to use Amplify on PC. Even basic commands like amplify --version throw this error.

I have already added path to system variables and Tried reinstalling amplify. I am not able to figure out where the problem is and there is no solution available online.[image: This the error i am getting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same, I fixed this by reinstalling amplify again :

```
npm uninstall -g @aws-amplify/cli
```

and then

```
npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli
```

Hope it will work for you !!

Comment: should we redo the config as well after the above command?