# The "Amplify" command is returning an error message that says "Pkg: error reading from file."

Tags: amazon-web-services

When I tried running amplify configure in my React project, I received an error message saying "Pkg: Error reading from file". I attempted to uninstall and reinstall @aws-amplify/cli, but this did not resolve the issue.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvJb7.png)

I tried to delete the node modules, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Pkg: Error reading from file" in Amplify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76667966/pkg-error-reading-from-file-in-amplify)